# Include build number and SVN URL into a release

Tags: svn, release

We're building our project using ant. I want to include a text-file containig the current SVN revision into the packaged release. My current idea is to do a `svn info` and pipe its output to a file that is then included in the release.

Have you done this before? Is there any standard way to do so?

Comment: Something to keep in mind if you use branches: The svn revision by itself is not enough to describe the version of the release. You'll want to have something to identify the branch too. (You could get that from the URL shown be `svn info`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) on the machine you can use the [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) command.
SubWCRev can replace parts of a given file with current svn version.

In my project I have a [template file](http://sharpkom.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sharpkom/SharpKom/AssemblyInfo.template.cs?revision=1331&view=markup) (note the string `$WCREV$`) and a [bat-file](http://sharpkom.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sharpkom/SharpKom/UpdateVersionFromSvn.bat?revision=554&view=markup) that generates a new file with the revision filled in.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a tool which is called

```
 svnversion
```

which is exactly intended for this purpose. svnversion is part of the command line client. The question is what kind of build system you are using?

Comment: svnversion does more work than "svn info": It checks for local modifications and detects mixed-revision working copies. Nice features, but with large checkouts it can be noticeably slow.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with a script that uses an awk script to generate a file called _vni that can be included. The generated file is obviously not controlled in SVN

### dorel

```
#!/bin/ksh
svn update
svn status
svn info | awk -f make-vers.awk
```

### make-vers.awk

This creates a file with HTML formatting and uses a background color from the `cols` array to allow rapid differentiation of releases. If you just want a text file strip all of the HTML gunk.

```
BEGIN{
cols[ci++] = "#3300FF";
cols[ci++] = "#B300FF";
}
/^Revision\:/{rev = $2}
/^Last Changed Author\:/{auth=$4}
/^Last Changed Date\:/{date=$4}


END{
    date = strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

    col = cols[rev%ci]
    vs = "<div id='vni'>\n";
    vs = vs "<p style='background-color: "col"'>BuildInfo: [PRODUCTNAME] V2.0 Product   ion: Release "
    vs = vs (rev)
    vs = vs " - " date
    vs = vs " ("auth") "
    vs = vs "</p>\n</div>"

    OF="vni"
    print vs >OF;
}
```